# Referential Integrity in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to verify referential integrity across all tables.

Here is what i have so far.

```
Select departId_pk, categId, itemNo, orderNom, 
     lineNo, memberId, wishListNo, memberId, sellerId, zip 
From department, category, item, line_item, tblorder, 
     shipping, wishlist, member, feedback, zip 
where categId_pk = departId_fk
```

I'm selecting the primary key from the tables where the `pk = fk`

I keep getting the "`departId`" in field list in ambiguous.

ok, here is what i Have now

SELECT 
    department.departId,
    category.categId,
    item.itemNo,
    tblorder.orderNo,
    line_item.lineNo,
    member.memberId,
    wishlist.wishListNo,
    zip.zip
FROM
    department,
    category,
    item,
    line_item,
    tblorder,
    shipping,
    wishlist,
    member,
    feedback,
    zip
WHERE
    category.categId = department.departId

I don't receive any errors but i don't see any results. IS there a way i can add more pk=fk to the where? I tried adding a , but i get an error.

Comment: I assume you mean `departId_pk` since that's the only one listed in your field list. Your issue is that it appears in more than one of your referenced tables. Add the table name itself:  `department.departId_pk`

Comment: Why? And how? This query doesn't 'verify referential integrity'. The foreign key itself already does that.

Comment: 6) Write a Query to verify referential integrity across all tables ‐ write one query that selects only primary keys from all tables
 SELECT lists all primary keys
 FROM lists all tables

 WHERE shows all relationships
 The query should not produce any error messages.